# Dplyr summarize_all divide rows with group_by and condition from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example data frame:

```
example_df = data.frame(Condition = c("UT", "UT", "TGF", "TGF"),
                        Drug = c("Drug1", "Drug2", "Drug1", "Drug2"),
                        Area = c(1.2, 3.1, 4.1, 2.2),
                        Shape = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5),
                        Max = c(5.5, 6.1, 7.5, 4.2) )
```

I want to divide rows with 'TGF' by rows with 'UT' within each "Drug" group. In this example, I have shown 3 numeric columns but in my actual data I have dozens of columns and rows. There 'NA' in the values as well.

This is what I have tried, but obviously not working

```
example_df_1 = example_df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Drug) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_all(~.[Condition=="TGF"] / .[Condition=="UT"])
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try: `summarize(across(2:4, ~.x[Condition == "TGF"] / .x[Condition == "UT"]))`?

Comment: thanks. looks like the across function comes from development version of dplyr? now stuck with Rtools

Comment: can also try: `summarise_at(2:4, ~.x[Condition == "TGF"] / .x[Condition == "UT"])` ... across for `dplyr` version 1.0.0+

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked beautifully :)